# How do I invert a hash with complex values?

Tags: algorithm, perl, dictionary, foreach, hashmap

I have this:

```
%lookup = (
    'Shelf' => { storage_types => 'Flat, Default' },
    'Locker' => { storage_types => 'Valuable' },
);
```

I want to get this:

```
%reverse_lookup = (
    'Flat' => 'Shelf',
    'Default' => 'Shelf',
    'Valuable' => 'Locker',
);
```

I can cycle through the storage types in a test, and check that a subroutine returns the correct location, for example.

I can't get my head around the multiple list expansion part.

```
%reverse_lookup = map { split(/,\s*/, $lookup{$_}) => $_ } keys %lookup; # wrong
```

I want to do it all concisely using map or similar, not a foreach loop.

Comment: What do you want to happen if you have `%lookup = ('Locker' => { storage_types => 'Valuable' }, 'Vault' => { storage_types => 'Valuable' })` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that with single map, as it iterate throught elements of %lookup hash, not throught lists inside. So in that case you will have in output hash the same number of keys as in source hash.

But you can use nested maps - first will iterate the main hash elements, second will iterate list inside.

```
my %lookup = (
    'Shelf' => { storage_types => 'Flat, Default' },
    'Locker' => { storage_types => 'Valuable' },
);
my %reverse_lookup = map { my $key_name = $_; map {$_ => $key_name} (split(/,\s*/, $lookup{$_}->{storage_types})) } keys %lookup;

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%reverse_lookup;
```

P.S. And what's wrong with foreach? :)

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to modify your original hash to be like this:

```
%lookup = (
    'Shelf' => { storage_types => [ 'Flat', 'Default'] },
    'Locker' => { storage_types => ['Valuable'] },
);
```

Then

```
%reverse_lookup = map {
       my $key = $_; 
       #$_ => $key foreach @{$lookup{$key}};
       map { $_ => $key } @${lookup{$key}};
    } keys %lookup;
```

Comment: Author wanted solution w/o foreach :)

Answer (score 1):

if you're only interested in the `storage_types` and want you have unreadable code, you could try:

```
%reverse_lookup = map { my $k = $_; map { $_ => $k } split /,\s*/, $lookup{$_}{storage_types} } keys %lookup;
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you *can* do this with one map, as long as you don't mind a useless use of map in void context (and even stupider things than that):

```
map { @reverse_hash{split /,\s*/, $lookup{$_}} = ($_x100) } keys %lookup;
```

It is concise, though.  And it even works!

Comment: And what if that list will have more that 100 elements? ;)

Comment: @mvf, the answer to that is simple: just replace 100 with 1000, or 10,000...there's no limit to the memory one can waste with this method! (Actually, in all seriousness, I wonder if the x operator actually creates an array of duplicate values.  I wouldn't be surprised if the interpreter is smart enough to avoid that.)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would code it

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %lookup = (
  Shelf => { storage_types => 'Flat, Default' },
  Locker => { storage_types => 'Valuable' },
);

my %reverse_lookup;

while ( my ($item, $info) = each %lookup ) {
  my @types = split /,\s*/, $info->{storage_types};
  $reverse_lookup{$_} = $item for @types;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%reverse_lookup;
```

**output**

```
{ Default => "Shelf", Flat => "Shelf", Valuable => "Locker" }
```